# How can I open the web console and the debugger at the same time in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, firefox-developer-tools

I would like to be able to see the console and the debugger tabs of Firefox's developer tools at the same time. They should both be relating to the same page. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By clicking on the three dots, top right in the dev tools, you can hide and show split console at the same time as the inspector etc. Also, suggests that robcee's answer still applies. Still valid in Firefox 2022 @mseifert

[image: split console]

Answer (score 7):

Firefox 28, released 18th of March 2014, has this feature:

[image: Debugger with Console below]

To enable it, just open the debugger and click the "Toggle split console" button. It's in the top bar of the dev tools, on the right-hand side.

Answer (score 5):

Also now possible to open the Console from any panel in the Developer Tools with the ESCape key.

Comment: It's 2022 and the Toggle Spit Console Button doesn't exist on my screen. Escape is all I needed to see the console again.